# Android RectF, Matrix scaling error

Tags: android, matrix

I want to scale all 4 points of RectF and put the result into another RectF.

```
          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preScale(2, 2);
         RectF src = new RectF(5,246,2,243);
         RectF dst = new RectF();
             matrix.mapRect(dst, src);
```

I have this result:
                 src == RectF(5.0, 246.0, 2.0, 243.0)
                 dst == RectF(4.0, 486.0, 10.0, 492.0)

But I expected something like
    dst.left = 2*src.left;
    dst.top = 2*src.top;
            etc...
     What is wrong?

Comment: Log.d src.width() and src.height()

Comment: src.width() == -3, src.height() == -3

Comment: so i hope you already know what's wrong?

Comment: Nop. Why should I care about height/width? I have a big array of  some start(x1,y1) and stop(x2,y2) points. And I need to scale each x and each y. So, I saved this array as List<RectF(x1,y1,x2,y2)>, because I think that "matrix multiplying" a bit faster.

Comment: use mapPoints(float[])

Comment: Impossible to use. Points are divided on logical blocks.

Comment: mapRect possible and mapPoints not? think it over...